# SQL Server add all rows where a condition is validate

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database in which I need to add all the cost for a job family.

I have a table like this

Table : **work**

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| wonum |   cost1   |   cost2   | wogroup |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|   1   |   30.12   |  157.14   |    1    |
|   2   |   110.10  |    0.00   |    1    |
|   3   |   12.67   |   45.45   |    1    |
|   4   |   0.00    |    0.00   |    4    |
|   5   |   400.00  |   11.54   |    4    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

I need to add cost1 and cost2 for all the row who have the same `wogroup` but only for the on `where wonum = wogroup`.

Like this

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
| wonum |   cost1   |   cost2   | wogroup |  total  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
|   1   |   30.12   |  157.14   |    1    | 355.48  |
|   2   |   110.10  |    0.00   |    1    |  null   |
|   3   |   12.67   |   45.45   |    1    |  null   |
|   4   |   0.00    |    0.00   |    4    |  411.54 |
|   5   |   400.00  |   11.54   |    4    |  null   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

In a perfect world, the null value would be the sum of cost1 and cost2 for the row but I'm not sure if it is possible...

EDIT: I can only do a select, it is for a BiRT report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this can change with more wonum being added, I'd have this as a `VIEW`

```
declare @work table (wonum  int , cost1 decimal (6,3),  cost2   decimal (6,3) , wogroup int)
insert into @work
values
(1,30.12,157.14,1),
(2,110.10,0.00,1),
(3,12.67,45.45,1),
(4,0.00,0.00,4),
(5,400.00,11.54,4)


select
   *,
   total = case when wonum = min(wonum) over (partition by wogroup) then sum(cost1) over (partition by wogroup) + sum(cost2) over (partition by wogroup) end 
from @work
```

**RETURNS**

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
| wonum |   cost1   |   cost2   | wogroup |  total  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
|   1   |   30.12   |  157.14   |    1    | 355.48  |
|   2   |   110.10  |    0.00   |    1    |  null   |
|   3   |   12.67   |   45.45   |    1    |  null   |
|   4   |   0.00    |    0.00   |    4    |  411.54 |
|   5   |   400.00  |   11.54   |    4    |  null   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

**YOUR QUERY**

```
select
       *,
       total = case when wonum = min(wonum) over (partition by wogroup) 
                    then sum(cost1) over (partition by wogroup) + sum(cost2) over (partition by wogroup) 
                    else null 
               end 
from work
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I can only do a Select (so I can't make a declare) it is for a report...

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, but here the declare is just for the test data... you wouldn't use it. You would just use the `select` and replace `@work` with your table name, which is `work`

Comment: @Charles That should be fine. scsimon just declared a table variable named `@work` to simulate your table without messing around in a real database.

Comment: @scsimon I think you easily could add an `else` clause to fulfill the "In a perfect world" requirement.